# C# foreach modifying list. Collection has been modified; the enumeration operation may not be performed

Tags: c#, foreach

I need help to understando this isssue...
In this code:

```
listaVideoTemp = listaVideo;
foreach (var itemVideo in listaVideo)
{
  if (itemVideo.ID == id)
  {
   listaVideoTemp.RemoveAt(i);                            

   listaServidorTemp = listaServidor;
                            
   foreach (var itemServidor in listaServidor)
   {
     listaVideoServidorTemp = itemServidor.PropListaVideo;

     foreach (var itemVideoServidor in itemServidor.PropListaVideo)
     {
       if (itemVideoServidor == id)
         listaVideoServidorTemp.RemoveAt(x);
       x++;
     }
    }
   }
   i++;
}
```

When execute `listaVideoServidorTemp.RemoveAt(x);` the item from `itemServidor.PropListaVideo` also is removed.
Can anyone help me?

```
Exception: Collection has been modified; the enumeration operation may not be performed.
```

Thanks.

Comment: `listaVideoTemp = listaVideo` does not make a copy, it points both variables to the same reference.

Comment: You can't modify a collection while you're iterating through it: `listaVideoTemp.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: Try `listaVideoTemp = listaVideo.ToList();`  Note you'll likely want to do `listaVideo = listaVideoTemp;`after the loop.

Comment: C# generic `List<T>` are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) - in other words, after the assigment, `listaVideoServidorTemp` is the __same object__ as `itemServidor.PropListaVideo` and changes to one effect the other. If you wanted a copy, you needed to do `listaVideoServidorTemp = new List<T>(itemServidor.propListaVideo);`.  This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - are you trying to count something in `x` and `i` the really hard way?

Comment: What is the purpose of `listaVideoTemp`? What is the purpose of `listaServidorTemp`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you can't modify a collection while you're iterating through it. In the following line, `listaVideoTemp` is a reference to `listaVideo`, which is the item you're iterating through:

```
listaVideoTemp.RemoveAt(i);
```

One way to resolve this would be to create a copy of the list instead:

```
var listaVideoTemp = listaVideo.ToList();
```